# Unwind segue doesn't work sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a bunch of views inside of a Nav controller.

The view hierarchy is LoginView -> NAV -> View 1 -> (present a VC. then dismiss) -> push V2 -> push V3 etc

At any view (V1, V2, V3 etc) there is a button that pushes the "Settings View". Inside the settings view there is a logout button.

In SettingsVC.m:

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"logging out");
    // do things here
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindToLogin" sender:self];
}
```

In LoginVC.m:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {
    self.emailField.text = nil;
    self.passwordField.text = nil;
    self.loadingSpinner.hidden = YES;
    self.failureLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.loginButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"unwinding?");
    NSLog(@"I hate unwinding");
}
```

I have hooked up the button in SettingsVC to `logout:sender:`. When I press the button it logs "logging out" and does all the things inside of the method, but it doesnt unwind to the LoginVC.

[Note: It is often the case that the Application launched and never loaded the Login View. (If there are stored credentials, it skips that view and logs in automatically. But even when the Login View is presented on startup, the unwind sometimes doesnt work.]

[Note 2: Often (but not always), if the last method I edit before running the app is `unwindToLogin:` the unwind works]

Please help

Comment: You've set the unwind segue in the storyboard correct?

Comment: yes I did. I've named the segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sometimes the Login Controller wasn't loaded at unwind time and therefore couldnt be unwinded back. Instead, I unwind to the landing VC which comes before the login, and immediately segue to the login VC